# Como criar uma função para deletar todos os registros do banco com PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Preciso criar um script para excluir todos os registros do meu banco em todas as tabelas, sem excluir as tabelas e reiniciar a sequência. Sei que devo utilizar o `TRUNCATE` ou o `DELETE`. Meu banco possui vários esquemas e cada esquema tem suas tabelas. Comecei a fazer a função da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.funcao_zerar_banco_dados()
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
DECLARE
tabelas RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tabelas IN
    SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE ' || tabelas.table_name || ' RESTART IDENTITY';
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Mas ao executar a função apresenta o seguinte erro:

> SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied: "pg_statistic" is a
> system catalog   Onde: SQL statement "TRUNCATE pg_statistic RESTART
> IDENTITY" função PL/pgSQL funcao_zerar_banco_dados() linha 8 em
> EXECUTE

Tentei dessa outra forma também:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.funcao_zerar_banco_dados()
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
DECLARE
tabelas RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR tabelas IN
        SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || tabelas.schema_name || ' RESTART IDENTITY';
    END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Mas aparece outro erro:

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "pg_toast" does not exist   Onde:
> SQL statement "TRUNCATE TABLE pg_toast RESTART IDENTITY" função
> PL/pgSQL funcao_zerar_banco_dados() linha 9 em EXECUTE

Se alguém souber como me ajudar, ficaria agradecida.

Comment: Você está tentando dar truncate em tabelas do sistema. Tente especificar apenas as tabelas ordinárias com `SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind= 'r'` no lugar de utilizar o Information Schema.

Comment: Mantendo a utilização do Information Schema você pode fazer: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'seu_esquema' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` ou ainda,caso existam vários esquemas, `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema <> 'information_schema' AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente usando o 
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema <> 'information_schema' AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

Ainda estou aprendendo a mexer com banco de dados e isso ajudou muito a terminar minha função, vou postá-la para quem tiver a mesma dúvida, pois foi difícil achar essa solução.

Comment: Nós [não somos um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum), não precisa marcar o título da questão com *[resolvido]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda dos comentários consegui finalizar a minha função. Segue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.funcao_zerar_banco_dados()
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
DECLARE
tabelas RECORD;
sequencia RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- SELECIONA TODAS OS ESQUEMAS QUE NÃO SÃO 'NATIVOS' POSTGRESQL
    FOR tabelas IN
        SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema <> 'information_schema' 
        AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Tabelas: %', tabelas.table_schema|| '.' || tabelas.table_name;
        -- EXCLUI OS DADOS EM CASCATA, CONCATENA O NOME DO ESQUEMA E DA TABELA
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE ' || tabelas.table_schema || '.' || tabelas.table_name || ' CASCADE';
    END LOOP;
        -- REINICIAR SEQUENCIAS
        FOR sequencia IN
            SELECT sequence_schema, sequence_name FROM information_schema.sequences
        LOOP
            PERFORM SETVAL(sequencia.sequence_schema || '.' || sequencia.sequence_name, 1, false);
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
RETURN;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Reiniciei as sequências utilizando o SETVAL devido ao banco conter sequências que não são campos de uma tabela, mas há também uma forma de se fazer utilizando o RESTART IDENTITY desde que as sequências sejam um campo da tabela, da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.funcao_zerar_banco_dados()
RETURNS VOID AS 
$$
DECLARE
tabelas RECORD;
sequencia RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- SELECIONA TODAS OS ESQUEMAS QUE NÃO SÃO 'NATIVOS' POSTGRESQL
    FOR tabelas IN
        SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema <> 'information_schema' 
        AND table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Tabelas: %', tabelas.table_schema|| '.' || tabelas.table_name;
        -- EXCLUI OS DADOS EM CASCATA, CONCATENA O NOME DO ESQUEMA E DA TABELA E REINICIA AS SEQUENCIAS
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE ' || tabelas.table_schema || '.' || tabelas.table_name || ' 
 RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE';
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
    END
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```